# iPhone SDK: Opening TableViewController with Navigation Bar

Tags: ios4, uinavigationcontroller, viewdidload, navigationbar

I'm creating my first iPhone app at the moment and it's going great, though I've come to  a bump in the road.  I'm trying to open up my settings view (a UITableViewController), though the navigation bar won't show up... I've successfully made the view open, just can't get the navigation bar to show up. Here's my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO];
self.title = @"Settings";

UIBarButtonItem *saveItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Save" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:nil];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveItem;

[saveItem release];
```

}

If I'm doing something wrong, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the navigation controller as a sub view to the main view.

for example,

[window addSubview:NavigationController.view]